# Pandas dataframe to count matrix

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
actual | predicted
------ + ---------
Apple  | Apple
Apple  | Apple
Apple  | Banana
Banana | Orange
Orange | Apple
```

I want this:

```
       |  Apple  | Banana  | Orange
------ + ------- + ------- + -------
Apple  |  2      | 1       | 0
Banana |  0      | 0       | 1
Orange |  1      | 0       | 0
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.groupby(['actual','predicted']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
predicted  Apple  Banana  Orange
actual                          
Apple          2       1       0
Banana         0       0       1
Orange         1       0       0
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.actual, df.predicted)
print (df)
predicted  Apple  Banana  Orange
actual                          
Apple          2       1       0
Banana         0       0       1
Orange         1       0       0
```

Comment: `In [142]: %timeit pd.crosstab(df.actual, df.predicted)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.04 ms per loop` and

`In [143]: %timeit df.groupby(['actual','predicted']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop`

Comment: @GregorSturm not a hack at all.  You are counting the number of times you see each combination.  To get the matrix, you unstack and fill nulls with zero.  I'm sure if you looked under the hood of `crosstab` your see much the same thing.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you. I am still surprised `crosstab` is slowier. But Ithink there is difference in implementation of functions.

Comment: +1 for the first solution involving `groupby()`, because it allows me to do `sum()` instead of `size()`, whereas the `crosstab()` solution does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='actual', columns='predicted', aggfunc=len).fillna(0).astype('int')
predicted Apple Banana Orange
actual                       
Apple         2      1      0
Banana        0      0      1
Orange        1      0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a shot in the dark, but I think you are looking for a [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print confusion_matrix(df['actual'], df['predicted'])
```